# ansible conditionals not stopping on matching first condition

Tags: ansible

I am a starter in ansible. I have to automate a installation where two things needs to be checked

1) Is it a redhat system (exit if not)
2) If 1) is true then check whether RAM is more than 8GB(if no then print message and exit)

This is my playbook

```
 - name: getting RAM details
   shell: free -m | grep Mem | awk  '{ print $2 }'
   register: ram
   when: ansible_distribution == "RedHat"

 - name: Checking OS
   debug: msg="current OS is {{ ansible_distribution }} which is not 
   supported. Should be redhat"
   when: (ansible_distribution!="RedHat")

 - name: Checking RAM
   debug: msg="current RAM is {{ ram.stdout }} GB. Should be 8 GB"
   when: (ram.stdout | int < 7698 )
```

The issue is the play is not exiting when the first scenario is matched. Its still going for the second scenario . I am a newcomer to the ansible world.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`assert` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/assert_module.html) (or [`fail` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fail_module.html)) instead of `debug`:

```
- name: Checking OS
  assert:
    msg: "current OS is {{ ansible_distribution }} which is not supported. Should be redhat"
    that: "ansible_distribution == 'RedHat'"

- name: Checking RAM
  assert:
    msg: "current RAM is {{ ram.stdout }} GB. Should be 8 GB"
    that: "ram.stdout | int > 7698"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with the tasks structure, please see below how it should look like:

```
- name: getting RAM details
  shell: free -m | grep Mem | awk  '{ print $2 }'
  register: ram
  when: ansible_distribution == "RedHat"
  
- name: Checking OS
  debug: msg="current OS is {{ ansible_distribution }} which is not supported. Should be redhat"
  when: (ansible_distribution!="RedHat")
  
- name: Checking RAM
  debug: msg="current RAM is {{ ram.stdout }} GB. Should be 8 GB"
  when: (ram.stdout | int < 7698 )
```

Regarding exiting, the idea of Ansible and the `when` condition is that it will process all tasks and will skip the ones that the `when` condition is not true. There is no "exit" way in the above code.

I understand what you were trying to achieve, but it doesn't work like that. Conditionally [importing tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/include_tasks_module.html) would be probably of use to you with a `when` condition, example:

```
- include_tasks: "{{ hostvar }}.yml"
  when: hostvar is defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `meta: end_play` to stop the play execution when either of the two condition is met.

```
- name: getting RAM details
  shell: free -m | grep Mem | awk  '{ print $2 }'
  register: ram
  when: ansible_distribution == "RedHat"

- name: abort if not Redhat or RAM less than 8G
  meta: end_play
  when: (ansible_distribution!="RedHat") or (ram.stdout | int < 7698 )
```